# This simple server-client program will not send/receive data other than the initial confirmation. Why?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, user-interface

I am doing a final project for my Comp Sci (Java) class and so the idea is that this is a simple server-client chat room.  Of course, my teacher, who is only really proficient with the aspects of the AP curriculum, knows between little and nothing about any of the components necessary to make such a program, so I am more or less on my own.  I have been using various StackOverflow posts and other examples of socket programs to reverse engineer sockets and figure out how to use them, but apparently, GUI can't update with the infinite loop necessary to check for received messages, so I set off back to google to find a better way to watch for messages. I came up with trying to use a propertyChange Listener, which apparently is something that you use when multithreading, another thing to add to the list of things neither my teacher nor I knew anything about.  I found a pretty straightforward and understandable (or so I thought) example to base my own code off of, and ran it.  Unfortunately, other than the initial confirmation that the server and the client had made contact, seemingly no data is being passed between the two programs.  Here is the client code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

class ClientRunnable extends newClient implements Runnable {
    public Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2702);
    public BufferedReader receiveRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istream));
    public String receptive = new String();
    public String sendToMessage = new String();
    public ClientRunnable() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    protected void initUI(ClientRunnable runnable) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String wrongSizeMSG = "Your username is not the right size.  It must be at least 4 characters and \nno larger than 20 characters.";
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        frame.show();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Please insert your username:");
        lblUsername.setBounds(131, 100, 172, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblUsername);
        lblUsername.show();
        UNInput = new JTextField();
        UNInput.setBounds(139, 125, 146, 20);
        frame.getContentPane().add(UNInput);
        UNInput.setColumns(10);
        UNInput.show();
        JButton btnGo = new JButton("GO!");
        btnGo.setBounds(170, 156, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnGo);
        btnGo.show();

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(msgDisplay);
        scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS );
        frame.getContentPane().add(scroll);
        JLabel lblWrongSize = new JLabel(wrongSizeMSG);
        lblWrongSize.setForeground(Color.RED);
        lblWrongSize.setBounds(10, 172, 414, 50);
        lblWrongSize.hide();
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblWrongSize);
        msgDisplay = new JTextArea();
        msgDisplay.setBounds(10, 11, 414, 168);
        frame.getContentPane().add(msgDisplay);
        msgDisplay.setColumns(10);
        msgDisplay.hide();
        msgDisplay.setEditable(false);
        msgDisplay.setText("");
        JLabel lblPrompt = new JLabel("Type:");
        lblPrompt.setBounds(10, 190, 46, 14);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblPrompt);
        lblPrompt.hide();
        txtEditor = new JTextField();
        txtEditor.setBounds(10, 215, 414, 35);
        frame.getContentPane().add(txtEditor);
        txtEditor.setColumns(10);
        txtEditor.hide();
        BufferedReader keyRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        OutputStream ostream = sock.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter pwrite = new PrintWriter(ostream, true);
        msgDisplay.setText("Start the chat, type and press Enter key.\n");
        pwrite.println("Success");
        btnGo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                username = UNInput.getText();
                System.out.println(username);
                UNInput.setText("");
                if(!(username.toCharArray().length < 4 || username.toCharArray().length > 20)){
                    btnGo.hide();
                    lblUsername.hide();
                    UNInput.hide();
                    lblWrongSize.hide();
                    msgDisplay.show();
                    lblPrompt.show();
                    txtEditor.show();
                } // if
                else {
                    lblWrongSize.show();    
                }
            }   
        });
        txtEditor.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                sendMessage = username + "> " + txtEditor.getText() + "\n";
                txtEditor.setText("");
                pwrite.print(sendMessage);
                msgDisplay.setText(msgDisplay.getText() + sendMessage);
                pwrite.flush();
            }
        });
    }

    private PropertyChangeSupport PCS = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        PCS.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();    
        } // try-catch
        try {
            setReceiveRead();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } // try-catch
    } // run

    public void setReceiveRead() throws IOException {
        receptive = receiveRead.readLine();
        PCS.firePropertyChange("In", receptive == null, receptive != null);
    }

    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
        newClient.msgDisplay.setText(newClient.msgDisplay.getText() + receptive + "\n");
    }
} // Runnable

public class newClient{

    protected JFrame frame;
    protected JTextField UNInput;
    public static JTextArea msgDisplay;
    protected JTextField txtEditor;
    public Socket sock;
    public InputStream istream;

    public newClient() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2702);
        istream = sock.getInputStream();
    }
    public BufferedReader receiveRead = new BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(istream));
    public String receptive = new String();

    public JTextArea getMsgDisplay() {
        return msgDisplay;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,     
        InterruptedException {
            final ClientRunnable runnable = new ClientRunnable();
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    runnable.initUI(runnable);
                    System.out.println("check there");
                } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        new Thread(runnable).start();
        System.out.println("Check here");
    }
    public static String username = new String();
    public static String receiveMessage, sendMessage = null;  
}
```

Here is the server code:

```
package serverPKGE;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      ServerSocket sersock = new ServerSocket(2702);
      System.out.println("Server  ready for chatting");

      Socket sock = sersock.accept( );                          
      BufferedReader keyRead = new BufferedReader(new         
      InputStreamReader(System.in));
      OutputStream ostream = sock.getOutputStream(); 
      PrintWriter pwrite = new PrintWriter(ostream, true);

      InputStream istream = sock.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader receiveRead = new BufferedReader(new             
      InputStreamReader(istream));

      String receiveMessage, sendMessage;               
      while(true) {
        if((receiveMessage = receiveRead.readLine()) != null)  {
           System.out.println(receiveMessage);         
        } // if        
        sendMessage = "Server> "
                + "" + receiveMessage; 
        pwrite.println(sendMessage);             
        pwrite.flush();
      } // while              
    } // main                    
} // server
```

I have only been working on one GUI at a time, so the Server code is much more oriented on the data transfer.  Can you see any apparent reason why the data wouldn't be recieved by nor sent from the client?  In a previous version of the client, there was a broken form of conversation where, for some reason, both sides of the connection would have to type something before either would be received and recorded, so I am assuming that the problem lies (at least mainly) in the client code.  Thanks for your help.

**Update**
Thanks to Scary Wombat for pointing out my error in the server code.  I have updated the code to reflect that and I also changed the code to fix a bug that opened two windows at the same time.  I still do not see where the code is going wrong.  Any other help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks again.

Comment: You need to exit your read loop when `readLine()` returns null. And don't ignore `IOExceptions`.

Answer (score 1):

You are blocking again waiting for input

Once

```
receiveMessage = receiveRead.readLine()
```

Twice

```
sendMessage = "Server> "
        + "" + keyRead.readLine();
```

Change to

```
sendMessage = "Server> "
        + "" + receiveMessage;
```